# Playframework - stop stream connection

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, akka-stream, twitter-streaming-api

I'm sending multiple requests to Twitter streaming api to track words and I want at some point of time stop tracking some word, how to close stream connection?

I have tried with SharedKillSwitch ([stream-dynamic](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.8/scala/stream/stream-dynamic.html)) but connection is not stoped.

```
val sharedKillSwitch = KillSwitches.shared(name)

val request = ws.url(url)
.sign(OAuthCalculator(consumerKey, requestToken))
.withQueryString(("track",query))
.withMethod("POST")
.stream()
.map { response =>
  if(response.headers.status == 200){
    response.body
      .scan("")((acc, curr) => if (acc.contains("\r\n")) curr.utf8String else acc + curr.utf8String)
      .filter(_.contains("\r\n"))
      .map(json => Try(parse(json).extract[Tweet]))
      .runForeach {
        case Success(tweet) =>
          println("-----")
          println(tweet.text)
        case Failure(e) =>
          println("-----")
          println(e.getStackTrace)
      }
  }
}

Source(Stream(request)).via(sharedKillSwitch.flow)
sharedKillSwitch.shutdown()
```

Comment: Have you tried inserting the kill switch flow into the response body stream: `response.body.via(sharedSkillSwitch.flow)`? When you stop consuming the body the connection should be closed.

Comment: Yes, that is solution. Thank you so much @Mikesname